# Change status depends ton child products magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to change the availability status of the configurable product depends on child products.

I found the following function

```
    <?php
        function getChildrenStockQTY($product, $stock_qty = 0) {
    if ($product->getTypeId() != 'configurable') return false;
    $simple_ids = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product->getId());
    foreach ($simple_ids[0] as $simple_id) {
        $simple_model = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple_id);
        $stock_qty += $simple_model->getQty();
    }
    return $stock_qty;
}

echo getChildrenStockQTY($product, $stock_qty = 0);

?>
```

When I place this code in /catalog/product/view.phtml is working but in

/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml I get the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null in
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I just call the functions.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
<?php $product_type = $_product->getTypeId(); ?>
```